# php mysql golf stats page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a site that tracks golf scores and gives them back to the user. each round, the player puts in their score and then I want to show how many pars, birdies, bogies, etc. the player had. each course has the hole's par value already in there. I need to take the player's score, figure out if it is -1, 0, +1, +2, etc. from the par value. then after that, I need to figure out how many birdies, pars, bogies, etc. there were for the entire round, and list them out on a table.

Does anybody know a way to do this? I have been sitting here pondering on this for some time now, and I can't think of how to do this.

Below  is my query:

```
$user = $_GET['user_id']; 
$get_player = "SELECT * 
         FROM users 
         WHERE user_id = '$user'";
$run_player = mysqli_query($con, $get_player); 
$row_player = mysqli_fetch_array($run_player);

$get_rounds = "SELECT *
               FROM user_rounds
               INNER JOIN courses 
               ON user_rounds.course_name=courses.course_name
               WHERE user_id = '".$row_player['user_id']."'";
$run_rounds = mysqli_query($con, $get_rounds);
while($row_rounds = mysqli_fetch_array($run_rounds)) {
```

and then from here I am trying to do the math for all of this. My tables have each of the scores stored along with the name of the course they played; so the two tables are matching up just fine.

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT

Below is my DB structure:

```
rounds 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_rounds` (
`round_id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
`date_played` date NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`course_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tee_played` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cor_rating` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cor_slope` int(100) NOT NULL,
`hole1` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole2` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole3` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole4` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole5` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole6` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole7` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole8` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole9` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole10` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole11` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole12` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole13` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole14` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole15` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole16` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole17` int(5) NOT NULL,
`hole18` int(5) NOT NULL,
`totOut` int(10) NOT NULL,
`totIn` int(10) NOT NULL,
`total` int(10) NOT NULL,

courses 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
`course_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`c_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`course_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`hole_1_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_2_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_3_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_4_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_5_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_6_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_7_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_8_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_9_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_10_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_11_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_12_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_13_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_14_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_15_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_16_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_17_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_18_par` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`hole_1_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_2_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_3_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_4_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_5_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_6_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_7_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_8_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_9_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_10_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_11_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_12_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_13_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_14_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_15_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_16_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_17_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_18_hc_mens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_1_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_2_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_3_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_4_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_5_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_6_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_7_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_8_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_9_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_10_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_11_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_12_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_13_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_14_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_15_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_16_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_17_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`hole_18_hc_womens` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
```

So the first one would be a birdie, etc. what I'm looking for is being able to get all of the pars, birdies, bogies, etc. together and then put them all together over all of the rounds that have been played.

Comment: I think you could use `join`, `count`, and `group by` to pull this data in one query, without DB structure though would be hard to say.

Comment: You will need to display your table structure for `user_rounds` and `courses`.  In addition you should look at `INNER JOIN` so you don't need to make 3 queries, and  learn how to make some basic arithmetic computations in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html)

Comment: Don't use a variable sourced by GET directly in a query.  Research SQL injection prevention.

Comment: Can you set up a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for your DB structure?

Comment: @RobbieAverill ... DB structure is updated now

Comment: @broserdooder - SQL fiddle please. Your example doesn't help, because I assume that you don't have multiple columns but rather *rows*. A fiddle is much easier for us to help you answer.

Comment: @RobbieAverill ... full structure above ... i don't like fiddle, sorry

Comment: I was wrong, you *are* using multiple columns. You should consider revising your database structure as this is going to make it difficult to write dynamic queries on.

Comment: @RobbieAverill ... THANK YOU!! you just gave me an idea that will make all of this easier ... figuring our the par value and difference on the initial form fill so all of the info is there for the picking when i need it ... thank you!!